# QSplashScreen not working properly in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I tried to make a splash screen using QSplashScreen but the image does not show properly.

the spalsh screen works (balnk), but the splash_loading.png is not showing.

this code is from an online tutorial:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.setWindowTitle('Just a dialog')
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit("Write something and press Enter")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),
                 self.update_ui)

    def update_ui(self):
        self.browser.append(self.lineedit.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, time

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    splash_pix = QPixmap('splash_loading.png')
    splash = QSplashScreen(splash_pix, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())
    splash.show()
    app.processEvents()

    # Simulate something that takes time
    time.sleep(2)

    form = Form()
    form.show()
    splash.finish(form)
    app.exec_()
```

[image: Splash Screen pyqt blank]

Comment: I remember facing the same issue. Are you using a PNG image with transparency? If so, try to use PNG without transparency and do not set the pixmap mask.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it but still getting the same problem problem. I will try JPG picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use sleep, you must process all events. Replace the lines between `app = ...` and `form = Form()` to:

```
start = time.time()
splash = QSplashScreen(QPixmap("screen.png"),  Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
splash.show()
while time.time() - start < 2:
    time.sleep(0.001)
    app.processEvents()
```

[image]